# Accept text/plain while @Consumes has application/json

Tags: rest, quarkus, mime-types, content-type, http-status-code-415

We migrated a DropWizard based REST service to Quarkus based one (version: 2.16.7.Final) using `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` extension. The APIs where the `@Consumes` annotation has `application/json` started failing in Quarkus with status code

> 415 (The content-type header value did not match the value in
> @Consumes)

when the request header has `Content-Type` set to `text/plain`
(Note: The request body payload parameter is defined as a String in the method signature).

While having `@Consumes` with `application/json` in DropWizard still serves requests that send `text/plain` in the `Content-Type` header. So this became an issue with respect to supporting existing clients with this migration (from DropWizard to Quarkus).

Is there any configuration option/workaround to allow `text/plain` in Quarkus when the `@Consumes` just has `application/json` (to relax and not return 415 in this scenario)?

If not, should we be adding `text/plain` also to the `@Consumes` tag in the code, is that the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should also be adding `text/plain` to the `@Consumes` annotation.

I am not sure why your case works in Dropwizard, but it seems like a pretty clear JAX-RS spec violation

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! We are fixing it on the client side